# Logging MERGE Changes in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am looking for a way to replicate the functionality of SQL Server's OUTPUT clause when using BigQuery's MERGE statement (assuming BQ does not have it already in some form and I missed it). The goal is to produce a table containing a count of the rows updated, deleted, and inserted by the BQ MERGE. A simple example, the following SQL statements:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `scratch.Events` AS 
 (SELECT 'ABC' as Id, '123' as Sku, 'Orange' as Name UNION ALL
  SELECT 'DEF', '456', 'Banana' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'GHI', '789', 'Honeycrisp' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'JKL', '012', 'Pear' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'MNO', '345', 'Strawberry');

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `scratch.NewEvents` AS
 (SELECT 'DEF' as Id, '456' as Sku, 'Banana' as Name UNION ALL
  SELECT 'GHI', '789', 'Apple' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'PQR', '456', 'Banana');

MERGE scratch.Events e 
USING scratch.NewEvents ne
ON e.id = ne.id AND e.sku = ne.sku
WHEN MATCHED AND e.name != ne.name THEN
  UPDATE SET name = ne.name
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT ROW
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN
  DELETE;
```

Produce:

[image]

SQL Server's OUTPUT clause could be used to produce the following:

[image]

Any ideas on how to efficiently get similar output in BigQuery would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I submitted this question to our Google Cloud Customer Engineer and he opened a feature request on their internal system. I will update here as I hear updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Google's [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#July_26_2021) - as of 2021-07-06 DML query jobs now return statistics about the number of rows that were inserted, deleted, or updated. For more information see [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_*](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-jobs#schema) and [DmlStats](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/DmlStats) in the Job resource type.

Answer (score 2):

There is not an "easy" way from everything I have been looking into on this.
One option would be that the data does exist in Cloud Logging as part of the [data_access log](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs#data_access_data_access).

Sample Output includes the following for the query you provided:

```
tableDataChange: {
    deletedRowsCount: "4"     
    insertedRowsCount: "2"     
    jobName: "projects/test-int/jobs/script_job_b82a439a5a1c9cebedeac579e82b0a32_2"     
    reason: "QUERY"     
   }
```

This can be brought into BigQuery via a [sink](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/auditlogs#stackdriver_logging_exports)

The other option which I cannot particularly make out the exact row count change is to query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.  There are a couple columns that may be useful in finding out the outputs but I have not exactly figured it out.  Wanted to put it out here though for you just in case you could.

```
select *
from `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
where 1=1
and job_id = 'script_job_0d7534fba1ac4cbb46c3096d7fb09b50_2';
```

Comment: I forgot to thank you Daniel! I explored your suggestions but decided to spend time on other parts of the overall effort and open a feature request through our Google contacts. I will update here when I hear back from them.